# How do I increase my client UDP receive buffer size in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, udp, buffer

I have a computer that communicates with a camera via UDP via a physical cable (no router or switch). The camera acts as the UDP server with the computer as client.  Once in a while the system hangs while an image is being transferred, line by line.  My Java software waits for a line of the image that is never received and I believe this could be caused by receive buffer overflow.

I've tried to increase the receive buffer maximum size in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem 1000000
```

My program requests 7000000 bytes by but at runtime reports that it received only 212992 bytes.

When I try to ask the OS the min, default, and maximum size:

```
sysctl -a | grep usb 
net.ipv4.udp mem 185535    247780  371670
```

How do I get a larger buffer?  Is sysctl even being read?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The edit to /etc/sysctl.conf was in error, it should have read as below and I should have increased the default value as well:

```
net.core.rmem_max=1000000
net.core.rmem_default=1000000
```

I don't know why the below wouldn't work when I entered it by hand but I wanted the values to be set at boot anyway.

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem 1000000
```